# WDDX crashes on XML from DB (CF 2016)

Tags: coldfusion, wddx, coldfusion-2016

When I query a DB table with an XML column

```
<cfquery name="qryData">
  DECLARE @data xml = '<ul class="xoxo"><li><span><b>Config</b> [<var>1</var>]:</span><code>compliance</code></li></ul>'

  SELECT @data AS Conf
</cfquery>
```

It crashed when converted to WDDX

```
<cfwddx action = "cfml2wddx" input = "#qryData#" output = "wddxText">
```

Adobe Bugbase: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4152876

Is there a better workaround than Casting to varchar(max) ?

Comment: James - I wonder why you need this to be XML inside the query? why not use ntext?

Comment: This is a simplified version of the issue. The actual xml comes from a normal DB column that I don't have control over

Comment: Hmm... not sure there's an answer here James. If Casting to TEXT is not an option you could try XMLFormat() prior to serializing to WDDX - or you could just URLEncode the whole thing before serializing. I suspect that the parser is choking over XML inside of XML - maybe it is trying to get an XML obejct rendered - then embed it in WDDX  (which would be a multi-noded XML object with lots of levels probably). IF it were me I would pick either WDDX or XML and stick with it - rather than imposing one on the other eh?

Comment: Per bug base: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4152876

This will be fixed in ColdFusion 2016 update 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was corrected with ColdFusion 2016 update 3

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2016-update-3.html